# GLaDOS (Portal 2) voice changer recommendation?

Tags: software-rec, skype, voice

Anyone know of a good program or a method that comes close to matching GLaDOS' voice from Portal games?

I'm going to surprise my boyfriend with a Skype call... mwahahaha

Comment: Great girlfriend

Comment: He's ignoring me for Portal. That's why.

Comment: Oh hahaa. Even better

Comment: Here's a related [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20879/has-anyone-ever-written-anything-on-the-particulars-of-glados-voice-processing) (On Gaming.SE).

Comment: @meiryo, I’m sure you’re great, but to be honest, I can’t really blame him. `:-)`

Comment: Haha, I know... but I finished Portal 2 - days ago!! Don't know what's taking him so long...

Comment: @meiryo now we know who the superior test subject is

Comment: I finished the game within 4 hours after it got released xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this in real time, unfortunately. Her voice is highly processed using formant shifting and manipulation of artifacting to get it to kind of slide up and down but still be robotic. It is demonstrated in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oQn66gvwKA&feature=player_embedded) video.

If you know any music production techniques or programs, you could get a similar effect by using the Mac's built in speech synthesizer and an Auto-tuner similar to what you hear on pop radio nowadays. Instead of automatically figuring out what pitch you're trying to achieve, you'd need to "force" it from one pitch to another by feeding the Auto Tune program a parameter - so if you're talking in the pitch of C, you get the GLaDOS effect by forcing it up to G or A. Again, not a super easy task to do in real time.

Wait, I started playing Portal 2 last night and ignoring my girlfriend. Am I going to get a call later?

Comment: you know, @melee, this is an ironic answer, coming from you :P - remember Steady Stating your girlfriend? :P

Comment: I'm just scared that I'm going to get a Skype call from GLaDOS later. "Hello Melee, we both posted some things you're going to regret.."

Comment: @melee you never know...

Comment: Better than getting a 3'x3' cube of dirt on my doorstep for playing Minecraft.

Comment: @melee Answer my question on Gaming.SE for extra rep! That's exactly the sort of response I wanted...:)

Comment: @melee did that really happen?

Comment: @Billare are you sure it is different enough from the other answer you have there? The link to the Melodyne method pretty much explains it all. I'll add it anyway.

Comment: @studiohack Nope. Not yet, at least :)

Comment: @melee Awesome, thanks for the technique... Now all I need is to come up with a witty line.

Answer (score 1):

On a mac the `say {text}` command in terminal will do a text-to-speech conversion that sounds somewhat like GLaDOS.  There are different voices available the default is female and sounds a bit lower tone than the Portal voice.

Comment: I just edited your answer to correct the command (it's `say` not `speak`). :)

Comment: If it's easier to do than Melodyne Uno then I'm up for it. Just need a Mac now...